# Add ruby script in gem to path

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface

I just created a very simple rubygem which has only one file that takes a couple of parameters.

I want to automatically add this ruby script to the path when I install it so that i can use it from anywhere in terminal like:

```
myruby "param1" "param2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this documentation from RubyGems](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable).

> Adding an executable to a gem is a simple process. You just need to place the file in your gem’s bin directory, and then add it to the list of executables in the gemspec. Let’s add one for the Hola gem. First create the file and make it executable:

[This article](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/06/14/how-to-write-a-command-line-ruby-gem/) also seems to be pretty good and it covers the essential details of adding an executable.